# Scrapy SitemapSpider only dupefiltering one item and finishing

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm running a scraper with a `FilesPipeline` which has so far downloaded 14,550 items. However, at some point it seems to have gotten 'stuck'; there was mention of 'loss' in the downloads. Since the scraper has a `WORKDIR` specified in the settings, I tried stopping it and restarting it.

Strangely, however, upon restarting it is encountering one item in the dupefilter and finishing (see logs below). I have no idea why the spider is behaving this way; can anyone point me in the right direction to debugging it?

```
scraper_1  | Tor appears to be working. Proceeding with command...
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:20 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: apkmirror_scraper)
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:20 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'apkmirror_scraper', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'apkmirror_scraper.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['apkmirror_scraper.spiders']}
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:20 [apkmirror_scraper.extensions] INFO: The crawler will scrape the following (randomized) number of items before changing identity: 32
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
scraper_1  | ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.extensions.spiderstate.SpiderState',
scraper_1  |  'apkmirror_scraper.extensions.TorRenewIdentity']
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
scraper_1  | ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
scraper_1  |  'apkmirror_scraper.downloadermiddlewares.TorRetryMiddleware',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
scraper_1  | ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.credentials] DEBUG: Looking for credentials via: env
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.credentials] DEBUG: Looking for credentials via: assume-role
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.credentials] DEBUG: Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.credentials] INFO: Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.loaders] DEBUG: Loading JSON file: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/data/endpoints.json
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.loaders] DEBUG: Loading JSON file: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/data/s3/2006-03-01/service-2.json
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.loaders] DEBUG: Loading JSON file: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/data/_retry.json
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.client] DEBUG: Registering retry handlers for service: s3
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.hooks] DEBUG: Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_post at 0x7f9739657a60>
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.hooks] DEBUG: Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f9739657840>
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.client] DEBUG: Switching signature version for service s3 to version s3v4 based on config file override.
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.endpoint] DEBUG: Setting s3 timeout as (60, 60)
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.client] DEBUG: Defaulting to S3 virtual host style addressing with path style addressing fallback.
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.credentials] DEBUG: Looking for credentials via: env
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.credentials] DEBUG: Looking for credentials via: assume-role
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.credentials] DEBUG: Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.credentials] INFO: Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.loaders] DEBUG: Loading JSON file: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/data/endpoints.json
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.loaders] DEBUG: Loading JSON file: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/data/s3/2006-03-01/service-2.json
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.loaders] DEBUG: Loading JSON file: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/data/_retry.json
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.client] DEBUG: Registering retry handlers for service: s3
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.hooks] DEBUG: Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_post at 0x7f9739657a60>
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.hooks] DEBUG: Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f9739657840>
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.client] DEBUG: Switching signature version for service s3 to version s3v4 based on config file override.
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.endpoint] DEBUG: Setting s3 timeout as (60, 60)
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [botocore.client] DEBUG: Defaulting to S3 virtual host style addressing with path style addressing fallback.
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
scraper_1  | ['scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline']
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://www.apkmirror.com/sitemap_index.xml> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
scraper_1  | {'dupefilter/filtered': 1,
scraper_1  |  'finish_reason': 'finished',
scraper_1  |  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 2, 11, 38, 21, 946421),
scraper_1  |  'log_count/DEBUG': 26,
scraper_1  |  'log_count/INFO': 10,
scraper_1  |  'memusage/max': 73805824,
scraper_1  |  'memusage/startup': 73805824,
scraper_1  |  'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 2, 11, 38, 21, 890151)}
scraper_1  | 2017-06-02 11:38:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
apkmirrorscrapercompose_scraper_1 exited with code 0
```

Here are some details on the spider. It is scraper `apkmirror.com` using a `SitemapSpider`:

```
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider
from apkmirror_scraper.spiders.base_spider import BaseSpider


class ApkmirrorSitemapSpider(SitemapSpider, BaseSpider):
    name = 'apkmirror'
    sitemap_urls = ['http://www.apkmirror.com/sitemap_index.xml']
    sitemap_rules = [(r'.*-android-apk-download/$', 'parse')]

    custom_settings = {
        'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 0,
        'CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT': 1,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 32,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 16,
        'TOR_RENEW_IDENTITY_ENABLED': True,
        'TOR_ITEMS_TO_SCRAPE_PER_IDENTITY': 50,
        'FEED_URI': '/scraper/apkmirror_scraper/data/apkmirror.json',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'apkmirror_scraper.dupefilters.URLDupefilter',
    }

    download_timeout = 60 * 15.0        # Allow 15 minutes for downloading APKs
```

where I have overridden the dupefilter class as follows:

```
from scrapy.dupefilters import RFPDupeFilter

class URLDupefilter(RFPDupeFilter):

    def request_fingerprint(self, request):
        '''Simply use the URL as fingerprint. (Scrapy's default is a hash containing the request's canonicalized URL, method, body, and (optionally) headers).'''
        return request.url
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `SitemapSpider`'s `start_requests()` [does NOT set `dont_filter=True`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/sitemap.py#L30), contrary to the [default `Spider` class](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py#L83).

So in effect, when restarting your crawl, `http://www.apkmirror.com/sitemap_index.xml` is presumably in your workdir as "already visited", hence filtered.

You can override your  `ApkmirrorSitemapSpider`'s `start_requests()` to set `dont_filter=True`. You can also open bug in scrapy.